# How to free up the memory of objects removed from a vec?

Tags: rust

If I have a `vec` of structs, calling `vec.remove(index)` will remove the struct stored in the `vec` at index `index`. However, the docs [don't explicitly mention](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove) what happens to these removed objects. How do I ensure they're freed up?

If objects in rust are freed up when they go out of scope, what happens to these removed objects, since the vector might go out of scope, but the removed objects could be dangling in memory? The code for the `Vec::remove(index)` seems to be only offsetting the elements in the vector to overwrite the element being removed:

```
// Shift everything down to fill in that spot.
ptr::copy(ptr.offset(1), ptr, len - index - 1);
```

Comment: Note that before the quoted `ptr::copy()` there is a `ret = ptr::read(ptr)` line that effectively moves the value from the vector into a local variable that gets returned (again by move) to the caller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Vec::remove(i)` copies the element out of the vector and shifts everything else down to fill the spot. It then returns that element to you. It is up to you to do whatever you want with that element. If you drop it, the object will be freed from memory, just like any other object:

```rust
vec.remove(i); // <- the element at index `i` is dropped and freed from memory
```